# Align a button group to the right end within a div

Tags: css, flexbox, less

There is a div containing some button groups.

```
.main-div {
    display: flex;
    .second-div {
                 //what to write here?
     }
}

<div class="main-div>
    //other divs
    <div class="second-div">
        <div>some button</div>      
        <div>some button</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want that a button group situated inside this div to be at the right end of the line.

I've tried multiple options like: `float: right;` ,    `justify-content: end;` ,`margin-right: 0px` but none of them have the wanted effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: show your html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `margin-left: auto;` to the element inside the flex element that you want tyo be right aligned.

```css
.main-div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="main-div" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" style="margin-left: auto;">Right</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use     `justify-content: flex-end;`

```css
.main{
display:flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help!